# Why does jQuery .attr always say that this is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code:

```
  $("#packing_list_css").on("click", ".crossable", function() {
    if ($(this).attr("text-decoration") == "none")
      $(this).attr("text-decoration", "line-through");
    if ($(this).attr("text-decoration") == "line-through")
      $(this).attr("text-decoration", "none");
  });
```

I've been testing different things, and anything that I call `.attr()` on always is undefined. For example, `x = $("h1").attr("font-size"); alert(x);` comes out as undefined.

I have `.crossable { text-decoration: none; }` set in my CSS. When I click inspect element, they all say that text-decoration is set to none. So I don't know why `.attr()` always says that it's undefined.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: *attr* is effectively a wrapper for the DOM *getAttribute* method, which sets and gets the value of an element's DOM attributes. *text-decoration* is not a DOM attribute, it is a property of an element's style object, e.g. `<p style="text-decoration:...">`.

Comment: Those are not attributes but css properties. Use `.css`

Comment: Also, doing `$(this)` many times is inefficient, do something like `var element = $(this); if (element.attr(...))` and so on. Where the choice is binary, the [conditinal operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12) `?:` (aka ternary operator) is handy.

Comment: use `var elem = $(".crossable");
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("font-size");`

Comment: Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is for HTML attributes, not for CSS properties.

You're looking for [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
var cssProp = $(this).css('text-decoration'); // Gets the CSS property's value
$(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through'); // Sets the CSS property's value
```

Comment: When I alert out `$(this).css('text-decoration');` it says `none solid rgb(0, 0, 0)` instead of just `none` like I specified. Why is that?

Comment: I thought that `text-decoration` could only have these values: `none|underline|overline|line-through|initial|inherit `.

Comment: @AdamZerner This is because [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) is a special "shorthand property" that actually can stand for several (in this case three) other actual CSS properties: [`text-decoration-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color), [`text-decoration-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line), and [`text-decoration-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style). The three alerted values correspond to these three properties.

Comment: now `x = $(this).css("text-decoration-line"); alert(x);` is giving me `undefined`. Why is that?

Comment: @AdamZerner My guess would be because you didn't explicitly set `text-decoration-line` in any CSS rules for that element. The `text-decoration` property may hold values that reflect its 3 longhand properties (and some of those values may be defaults), but it won't explicitly set those properties individually, as they are still different properties. Note that `text-decoration`, while a shorthand for other properties, is still its own property in its own right. Other shorthand properties behave similarly. This behavior could also be browser-dependent (but I would doubt so in modern browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Text decoration isn't an attribute it's a CSS value. Attributes are things like href, class and id on an HTML element.

Try this:

```
$(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
```